# How to add progress bar while loading Radgrid in Winforms

Tags: winforms, telerik, radgrid

I am having Radgrid with more than 100000  Records so I want to add progress bar before loading and also want to add progress bar in filters.

How to add progress bar in Radgrid winforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve your problem using `RadWaitingBar`. Add `RadWaitingBar` and set property `AssociatedControl` to  your grid.

[Here you can find telerik doc. with samples](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/track-and-status-controls/waitingbar/associated-control)

```
 this.yourRadWaitingBar.AssociatedControl=this.yourGrid;
 this.yourRadWaitingBar.StartWaiting();
```

Comment: this.yourRadWaitingBar.AssociatedControl is not a member of telerik.wincontrols.ui.radwaitingbar... how to include associatedproperty?

Comment: Associatedcontrol property shows error . it is not a member of telerik.wincontrols.ui.radwaitingbar

Comment: It is, i added documentation you can check it.